# Amazon pinpoint sms adding own phone number to send sms

Tags: python, sms

I hope you all are having a great day. I was checking amazon pinpoint sms and it worked fine on test messaging part.

I have two questions though.

1. Using my own phone number for sending and receiving messages. The normal way the pinpoint service is this to request a phone number. Is it possible to setup my own phone number as a service that does the messaging and receiving part?

In the case of if 1 is not possible:

2. The amount of numbers I can buy from the phone services are limited. The cheapest one is USA and I am normally ok with buying it but this limits the number of messages I can send to it since I am not from USA and that type of message will cost much more than the normal messaging(SMS).

I hope my question is clear, please comment on whichever part on the question should be updated.

P.S I am from Turkey so using another number from Turkey through Amazon would be nice too.

Thanks :)